# Content Security Policy directive when trying to use EJS include

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have a simple ejs file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>test</title>

</head>


<body>
<% include ../../partials/nav.ejs %>

<h1>Hello</h1>
<h4><%= uid %></h4>
</body>
</html>
```

This is served using NodeJS:

```
app.get('/testing/test/:uid', function (req, res) {
    res.render('test', {uid: req.params.uid})
});
```

Currently nav.ejs is a blank file.

When I remove the `<% include ../../partials/nav.ejs %>` line, the page loads just fine and the uid from the URL gets inserted into the the `<h4>` tag. However, as soon as I include that line I get the following error:

```
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-o6wSC15InKzMdQsAjlOwalELkGSpN0I4/fzIfw2Ckvg='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

However, I don't really understand this because I have no styling in either nav.ejs or my main ehs file. There are no scripts or anything like that. It's literally just a blank ejs file that I'm trying to

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Hey were you ever able to figure this out?